# What is executed when "Run tests" is clicked in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When running Android unit tests using Android Studio "Run tests" functionality (e.g. button click) all tests will pass. But when running same tests using `./gradlew test` some tests fail. This leads me to the question: is there any difference between executing test in Android Studio or using gradle? What exactly is executed when running unit tests via Android Studio?